# Fixing a disproportionately weak squat

Tags: powerlifting, crossfit

I've been doing Crossfit full-time (5-6 days/week) for a year now, and I have a really, stubbornly weak squat. It's so weak that it's always my limiting factor on compound movements like thrusters, cleans & jerks (not my upper body). I have very long limbs in general and especially long femurs, but it would surprise me if that's the only problem.

#### My stats and 1RMs

```
Body weight: 135 lb
Sex: Female
Back squat: 103 lb
Front squat: 93 lb
Deadlift: 183 lb
Squat snatch: 68 lb (the limiting factor is the squat)
Power clean: 103 lb (better than my squat clean because no squat)
Strict press: 68 lb
Strict pullups: 5
```

Here are some hypotheses I have considered and ultimately dismissed (but correct me if I should reconsider):

#### Hypothesis #1: I should do Starting Strength.

*Counter-evidence*: I did SS assiduously(*) for 9 months before starting Crossfit. It worked moderately well for most of my lifts except my squat, which plateaued extremely fast. Now that I'm doing Crossfit, my other lifts are again improving, while my squat rarely budges.

#### Hypothesis #2: I should eat more.

*Counter-evidence*: I eat around 2400 calories/day with a lot of protein, and my squat is the only lift that's so stubborn, so I assume this isn't the problem.

#### Hypothesis #3: I have a mobility problem.

*Counter-evidence*: If anything, the coaches at my gym comment that my mobility is unusually good. I can sit in an ass-to-grass squat with my knees touching my chest and my butt touching the ground, for example.

#### Hypothesis #4: I have a squatting form problem.

*Counter-evidence*: I'm lucky that my Crossfit gym has a strong emphasis on lifting technique, and the coaches think my squat form is reasonable. Their main comment is that I have a hard time keeping my torso upright (especially in back squats, but also front squats). I've tried to work on this, but it seems partly like a necessarily evil given the extreme length of my femurs compared to my upper body.

## So what should I do to suck less at squatting? Are there diagnostics I can use to figure out what the problem is?

(*) Pun intended. Not going to lie.

Comment: Please add a video of you squatting, shot from the side.

Comment: These [form check guidelines](http://startingstrength.com/resources/forum/technique/20249-posting-technique-forum.html) are a good summary of how to get the best help from video.

Comment: I appreciate your "SS assiduously" pun. ;-)

Comment: I strongly recommend you to watch this video [How to Squat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2b8UdqmlFs) and apply those techniques on your training.

Comment: Appreciate the comments re: uploading a video. I'm a bit wary of uploading videos to a public forum, but I've been specifically asking multiple experienced weightlifters to look at my form in person (hence also the slow response here). They all have the same comment about my torso folding forward too much.

Comment: lack of activation of posterior chain? This collection of muscles is inherently stronger than anything you will use naturally stepping from an office chair into a gym.  Also, being naturally flexible suggests muscles with attachments closer to the joints.  If you are naturally flexible **and** tall, this could indicate poor biomechanical leverage for a task like a squat--and so muscular development might not increase your squat numbers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a hybrid hypothesis: your squat form is wrong and has been wrong for close to two years, you're not working on fixing it, and you're spending your recovery budget on WODs and other lifts. Conversely, your squat--like anyone's--will get better if you do it right and focus on it.

Here's the part where I say that we can't really know anything without seeing a form check. It's impossible to know what's wrong with your squat without seeing you squat. It's impossible to know what went wrong with your prior lifting experience without reading your hopefully detailed lifting-and-eating log. These facts should be self-evident.

So why do I suspect the problem is just bad form? Because ~100 pounds is right where otherwise relatively athletic women your size often see trouble in the squat. It's where the lift stops being a challenge that can be overcome by blindly pushing a little harder. The good-morning'd squat stops working. It's when you have to actually lift the weight correctly or it will not work.

You say your mobility is great because you have a deep squat, but how upright is your chest while you do that? Mobility for the squat is not limited to what you describe. Is your back properly arched in its natural curve at the bottom, or do you have to hunch forward? In your loaded squats, maybe you're losing tightness with an extreme butt wink in the bottom, or you're unable to maintain an upright torso. You even hint that this is the problem, but try to get off the hook on grounds of anthropometric idiosyncrasy. I have long femurs too--the solution was *more* of a focus on impeccably upright front squats and chest-upped high-bar back squats. Weird dimensions often mean one benefits from unusual focus in another area, like ankle mobility, hip flexor flexibility, or mid-back strength.

Regardless of what the problem is, I bet that front or high-bar back squats before each CrossFit workout would solve the problem. Doing 3 to 5 heavy sets of 5 at least twice a week and 70-80% of that on the other days would probably suffice.

Comment: The man speaks truth. +1

Comment: My answer would pretty much be the same as this. I'm 6' 6", with long legs and used to struggle with squats a lot, until I decided to squat every day (in the gym with weights as well as outside the gym). Consequently, my squat form improved dramatically and more importantly for me, my confidence at the bottom of the squat (or the catch position in the Olympic lifts) got a lot better

Comment: I think this is a good answer, except that squatting heavy more than three times per week probably is too much, even for a novice trainee.  I suggest eliminating the CrossFit entirely until you're squatting a bodyweight-loaded barbell (that is, 135lb) for 3x5.

Comment: @CCCV Excellent point about too much intensity. I edited my recommendation. I don't want to get so far into the OP's business as to suggest replacing their entire current workout regimen, but I see that point too.

Comment: Fair enough, @Dave Liepmann!

Comment: This is very interesting. At what point would you say some good-morning cheating stops working altogether for guys? I'm about 5'5" and 154 lbs and always notice my knee angle opening up a bit too fast relative to my hips on squats, which I figure is because my posterior chain is relatively good (strong deadlift compared to squat) but my quads are a disaster. I'm wondering if it's still on an acceptable level or if I'm gonna hit a wall soon that I might avoid with some technique work. Just like OP squats are a real struggle for me.

Comment: @G_H It stops working when it stops working. I've noticed that guys roughly my size (5'10'', 170-180) encounter it circa 220lbs, maybe 250-260 if they really push. It's different for everybody but doing it wrong stops working with heavier weight. For you, if your hips rise faster than your shoulders, that's bad, and your deadlift doesn't excuse your posterior chain. For me a similar hips-first problem was fixed by a stronger back—low, mid, and upper—achieved with heavy front squats and insisting on "chest up" for a rep to count during high-bar back squats.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann Currently on 225 lbs for sets of 5 squats. I've started paying attention to keeping my chest up more a while ago, which probably saved me from stalling altogether. On the good reps I usually manage to keep the hips and shoulders rising in sync, but I tend to end up with a very vertical shin angle. Not sure if that's a problem. Now I know where to look first when I hit a wall. Thanks!

Comment: @G_H Switching to high-bar squats can help, as well as programming in front squats for 5x8-10 at a lower weight. I personally found my good morning occurring near my max and if my weight shifted towards the front of my feet. Filming yourself does help, use your warm-up to do slow squats with careful form to train your balance.

Comment: Sorry for the slow acceptance of this answer, but thanks -- very helpful, and I'm going to give this a serious try.

Comment: @half-pass Best of luck. It's a lot of fun to see the rewards of fighting for a really beautiful upright squat.

Answer (score -1):

Having done Crossfit myself, there wasn't nearly enough back squat work to get good at back squatting. Perhaps your body requires more volume that SS can't give you. Once your form is locked in, I would try a squat specific program like Smolov.

Comment: Depends on the box. My gym does lifting cycles where they focus on improving specific lifts be using %1RM-style programming. With weightlifting classes I hit back squat 3 times a week and have managed to increase my 1RM from 120k to 130k.

Comment: @JJosaur True but at your box is squatting the focus of the WOD or is a precursor to the metcon for the day? At the three boxes I have been to it was the latter. If the OP really wants to improve the squat, she needs to squat...alot.

Comment: @salisboss Programming strength exercises before WODs is one of the best versions of CrossFit. It's the opposite—only squatting *in* the WOD—that I expect to help little.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann We are starting to have a Crossfit debate but I would agree that squatting in the WOD would have little help on a 1RM squat (IME back squats don't show up in the WOD all that much if at all, more front squats). Plus the rep ranges in a WOD do not lend themselves to maximal strength.